# What protocols are available for performing remote operations from within Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf, rpc

I have a Silverlight app which currently uses a WCF to interact with the back-end.  For some reason, the asynchronous calls occasionally (in fact semi frequently) vanish into thin air.  We've yet to set up tracing or logging, however I've 'synchronized' some of the more critical calls with some cheap hacks and that seems to have mitigated the problem.  In any event, it seems that for some reason WCF calls get dropped.  My questions is what other communication protocols are available?  All we need to do is a get a hold of a our db and call a bunch of stored procedures and the like.  Is there a more bulletproof way of doing this?  Currently what we do is test the return of each call just to be sure, and if it seems to have failed, i just try again a few times and usually it works.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks,
brian

Answer (score 2):

[WCF RIA Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707344(VS.91).aspx) was built with Silverlight in mind. Any Silverlight project can have a WCF RIA Services link as seen on this screenshot of the project settings of a Silverlight project:

[image: WCF RIA Services link in Silverlight project settings]

Comment: Are you able to run stored procs with RIA?  We had originally considered this but decided against it because it didn't seem to quite fit our needs.  Additionally, does RIA sit on top of the WCF?  It seems that WCF is what's to blame for our dropped calls.

Comment: You are able to connect the RIA service to frameworks like the Entity Framework or to your own data acccess framework based on say stored procedures. The RIA services sits on top of WCF and in general I don't think it suffers from "dropped calls".